# Inconsistent behaviour with Number.toPrecision(2)

Tags: javascript, rounding, precision

I'm programming a calculator for flow in open channels where the user can input a 'roughness coefficient' that I'd like to round to two significant digits. But I'm getting inconsistent results.

```js
console.log(0.00135.toPrecision(2))// -> 0.0014
console.log(0.0135.toPrecision(2)) // -> 0.013
console.log(0.135.toPrecision(2)) // -> 0.14
```

All I'm doing is shifting the decimal point (multiplying the number by 10) and would assume that the result should also be shifted by a factor of 10. But in some cases the 5 rounds up and in other cases the 5 rounds down. I realize there are 'odd-even' rules that can be used for rounding but they don't apply in this case when multiplying/dividing by 10.

Some other 'puzzling' (to me, at any rate) results:

```js
console.log(0.0235.toPrecision(2))// -> 0.024
console.log(0.0245.toPrecision(2))// -> 0.025
console.log(0.0255.toPrecision(2))// -> 0.025
console.log(0.0265.toPrecision(2))// -> 0.026
console.log(0.0275.toPrecision(2))// -> 0.028
console.log(0.0285.toPrecision(2))// -> 0.029
```

Is it to do with floating point representation for small numbers? I'm getting the same behavior on FF and Brave. Is there an easy fix that anyone can suggest?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: The solution, BTW, is to use [decimal.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js) instead of inventing the wheel.

Comment: Never heard of "toPrecision" but it seems a very weird method. On Edge I get `0.0035.toPrecision(2) -> '0.0035'`, but the second example yields the values you reported. I have always used `toFixed`

Comment: Yeah the first code block in OP questions is very likely not copy&pasted but written and they probably screwed up ... `0.0035` cannot possibly "round" in any way to `0.0014`. They probably edited incorrectly the input or output or both

Comment: `0.00135`, `0.0135`, and `0.135` in the first snippet would output OP's results. If these are the ones you were using @dmorg, then please [edit] your question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your claimed issues with the first part. But the second part, yes that may be an issue with floating point arithmetics, because if you do `0.0255000000001.toPrecision(2)` it yields the correct result `0.026`

Comment: Yes, it's most certainly a floating point representaion problem. Because for instance `0.0255` converted to a binary floating point representation is `0.025499999523162841796875` and this will be rounded to `0.0255` ...

Comment: @GACy20 the difference between `toFixed(2)` and `toPrecision(2)` is, that `toFixed(2)` rounds to exactly 2 digits after the comma, whereas `toPrecision(2)` aims to keep 2 significant (ie different from 0) digits, regardless of whether they are before or after the comma. See this fiddle for an illustration of the difference https://jsfiddle.net/w25ybqo4/

Comment: @GACy20 toFixed() gives decimal places and toPrecision() gives significant digits. They are context specific and not interchangeable.

Comment: @Kaiido Guilty as charged. My apologies. Now corrected.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I'm not sure why using a common JS method is reinventing the wheel. Or why using a library instead of a simple function call is the answer. Thanks anyway.